# Appending in lists of list

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am having the following lists:

```
listA = [[1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1]]
listB = [1,2,3,4]
```

and I want:

```
listC = [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1, 3], [1, 1, 1, 1, 4]]
```

I am using the following code:

```
for i in range(len(listA)):
     listA[i].append(listB[i])
```

The result is ok but I want to do that in one line using list comprehension(if possible, or another more elegant way). I can understand a simple list comprehension but not more complicated.

Comment: So you want to append the 1st element in B to the 1st list in A, the 2nd element to the second list in A etc.?

Comment: Yes.Thanks for the comment, I edited my question to be more clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

List comprehension is not used to alternate (modify) existing objects, but to create new ones, you can do it for example through zipping your elements

```
listA = [a + [b] for a, b in zip(listA, listB)]
```

However notice that this actually is linear in time, it destroys the old `listA` and creates the new one, while your original code is more efficient as it only modifies the `listA` object.

The most efficient and pythonic way would be to connect these two and call

```
for a, b in zip(listA, listB):
    a.append(b)
```

Answer (score 7):

This should do the trick:

```
[x + [y] for x, y in zip(listA, listB)]
```